# Telerik grid with dropdownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu, telerik

Now i have tryed to solve the problem for several hours and im about to give up...

I am using MVC 3 grid kontrol from Telerik. In my grid i want dropdownlists selected item to be corresponding to Role of the user. Dropdownlist have all the User Roles.

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid").TableHtmlAttributes(new { width="800"})
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        //if (userIsInWhateverRole){
        //    columns.Template(o => Html.Action(GenerateYourLinkStuffHere));
        //}
        columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Email).Width(120);
        columns.Template(
            @<text>
                @Html.DropDownList(item.Role, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)item.Roles)
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => item.Role, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)item.Roles)
            </text>
        ).Width(120);
    })
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .Filterable()
    .Pageable(paging => paging.PageSize(5))
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should try something like this

in your model, add an attribute `[UIHint("Role")]` for Role property (keep it simple string)

load the grid as it is

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Name).Width(150);
columns.Bound(o => o.Email).Width(120);
columns.Bound(o => o.Roll).Width(120);
```

add a view named `Role.cshtml` inside of EditorTemplates `(this is a folder, directory like as  View/(controller-specific-folder)/EditorTemplates)` and finally put your dropdown in the `Role.cshtml` view.

For more details http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/combo-box-in-grid.aspx
sample http://www.telerik.com/ClientsFiles/327900_TelerikMvcGridEditingDropdown.zip

Comment: it works, but what do i have to do to get it editable from begning? so i dont have to press update/edit buttons?

Comment: then make sure Model.Role is type IEnumarable<SelectListItem> and write as `columns.Template(
                @<text>
                @Html.DropDownList("dropdown-name",Model.Role)
                </text>);`

Comment: i cant use Model.Role , it keep saying that it can not resolve the symbol... i can use item.Role.  I have changed type of Role to IEnumerable<SelectListItem>... any ideas? my model in view also have to be IEnumerable<UserViewModel>?

Answer (score 1):

So, instead of

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => item.Role, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)item.Roles)
```

You should do this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => item.Role, new SelectList(item.Roles, item.Role))
```

And that should solve your problem.